# Get item from set python

Tags: python, set

I have a set which contains objects which I have the `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions defined for.

I would like to be able to check if an object with the same hash is in the set and if it is in the set to return the object from the set as I need the reference to the object.

```
class SetObject():
    def __init__(
        self,
        a: int,
        b: int,
        c: int
    ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SetObject ({self.a} {self.b} {self.c}) (id: {id(self)}"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, SetObject) \
               and self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()

    def __hash__(self):
        # Hash only depends on a, b
        return hash(
            (self.a,self.b)
        )

x = SetObject(1,2,3)
y = SetObject(4,5,6)

object_set = set([x,y])

print(f"{object_set=}")

z = SetObject(1,2,7)
print(f"{z=}")
if z in object_set:
    print("Is in set")
    # Get the object in set which is equal to z
    for element in object_set:
       if element == z:
           print(element)
           z = element

print(f"{z=}")
```

Comment: What's the problem? When I run your code, the last line prints the `(1 2 3)` object.

Comment: Sorry, the code does work however I haven't worked with sets much so I feel there must be a better way to index into it without looping over all elements

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to return the element with a particular hash. I don't think so, since there's normally no reason to assume that this is unique.

Comment: Would a dict be a better datastruct for this problem then? I just assumed that as the set uses the hash to know if an element exists in a set I should be able to retrieve the item with that hash

Comment: I just came up with that same idea, I was writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a set, use a dictionary where the keys and values are the same element. Then you can look use the value as a key and return the element.

```
x = SetObject(1,2,3)
y = SetObject(4,5,6)

object_set = dict([(x, x),(y, y)])

print(f"{object_set=}")

z = SetObject(1,2,7)
print(f"{z=}")
if z in object_set:
    print("Is in set")
    z = object_set[z]

print(f"{z=}")
```

If you want to simplify this, you could define a subclass of `dict` that automatically makes the values the same as the keys.

Comment: Would using the object as the dict key be okay performance wise? I like this solution, this is what I was imagining set was performing under the hood except using `hash(x)` as the key

Comment: Yes, performance should be fine. This is conceptually what a `set` is, but the implementation may be a little different.

Answer (score 2):

As Alessi 42 puts in the comments, if you can, just use a dictionary, it will be simpler and *way* more efficient than this example.

The only way of retrieving an specific instance of a set is to perform some set-operations that would involve creating auxiliar sets:

```
def getinstance(set_, member):
    set2 = set_ - set((member,))
    return (set_ - set2).pop()
```

It is obvious that performance wise this is a lot worse than simply using a dictionary.

This simple class can be used to test the above function:

```
class IdInt(int):
    count = 0
    def __new__(cls, value):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, value)
        cls.count += 1
        instance.id = cls.count
        return instance
```

And on the interactive prompt:

```
In [29]: myset = set()

In [30]: a = IdInt(0)

In [31]: b = IdInt(0)

In [32]: myset.add(a)

In [33]: getinstance(myset, b) is a
Out[33]: True

In [34]: getinstance(myset, b) is b
Out[34]: False
```